# What performance considerations should I care when designing a table that will not receive updates

Tags: sql, database-design

We have in our DB a Table which contains a dozens of rows. 
The only DML's which applied on the Table are :

1.**Inserts** - Rows are inserted due to Trigger execution on another table .

2.**Deletes** - A schedualed procedure is loading requested records to temp table, working with these records and afterwards deleting them from the specific table (there is also a SELECT from the table in order to populate the temp table each time the procedure is running).

We've build the Table with PK and when we run the deletion,
the table is deleted row by row with the ID of the PK column.

just to clarify, we dont have any **UPDATES** opreations on the table .

Is there any specific guidelines or recommendations when creating such a table ( without updates ) ?

Thx for your answers .

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but if you want to know how to protect a table from accidental updates, you can create a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger which will roll back the current transaction and throw an error...what exactly are you looking to do?

Comment: The question sounds so strange to me! Are you sure you told us everything about your table, or do you have anything else you don't want to tell us about?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing special about a table that you don't intend to update.

You could, if you wanted for security reasons, deny update permissions to everyone, since you really only want to allow inserts, deletes, and selects, but there's nothing special about the design, and nothing forcing you to do so.

Comment: @lc's suggestion about the trigger in the comments on your question is a good one as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can create this table in another schema and grant select, insert, delete to your schema without granting update
so any trying to execute update statemets from your current schema will not executed.

here is an example:

```
connect system/manager

grant connect, resource to user1 identified by user1; 

grant connect, resource to user2 identified by user2;

disconnect

connect user1/user1

create table user1.table1(col1 number, col1_desc varchar2(16));

grant select, insert, delete on user1.table1 to user2;

disconnect

conn user2/user2

select * from user1.table1

insert into user1.table1 values (1, 'insert-user2');

commit;

insert into user1.table1 values (2, 'insert-user2');

commit;

delete from user1.table1 t where t.col1 = 2;

commit;

update user1.table1 t set t.col1_desc = 'ins-user2' where t.col1 = 1;

commit;

-- last update statement will throw ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

note: you can use table1 table name directly from user2 by using synonym for user1.table1

regards,

Comment: Thx for your answer but my Question was not related to permissions or privilges issues, its related to design and performance considerations , if there are while creating a table without update operations such as : what is the prefered index ? add pk ? etc..

Comment: Hi, according to oracle documentation there is nothing related to "create table" statement prevents "update", it's privilges issue as you say. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7002.htm

Comment: You are presuming Oracle, but the asker said nothing about it.